# Is it possible to modify the alert body of a NSLocalNotification before displaying it and after having scheduled it?

Tags: ios8, scheduling, uilocalnotification

This is my code to schedule the **UILocalNotificaiton** and repeat it every minute:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:delay];
localNotification.alertAction = nil;
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

localNotification.alertBody = @"Initial message";
localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Return to App", nil);
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Once the notification triggers I would like to change the alert body (title, etc..) to reflect the number of times that this notification has been triggered.

This is my code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
{
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.alertBody = @"Changing body"; //This is where I will put the count
}
```

However the body does not get changed.

Answer (score 0):

Dont remember for sure, but doesnt it contains setAlertBody method?

Comment: Yes it does but that's equivalent to setting the alert body directly "localNotification.alertBody = @"Initial message";"

Comment: Have you checked it? Sometimes you need to use method instead property in order to assign new value.

Comment: Yes I did, no difference sadly

Comment: Right... And what makes you not being able to create new notification and saving value of how many times it has been triggered in field?

Comment: It simply doesn't work if I create a new notification. That would be the best approach